# Corrupted kmz file with parse error?

Tags: google, kmz

I have a challenge viewing my file.

I get the following error (Failed: parse error at line 16032, column 25) when i try to open on Google.

I am unfamiliar with coding.

Comment: Is it possible to load file with issue on this page please

Comment: Can you please post a link to your file? You can upload it for example with Dropbox.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate whether you are trying to view your file using Google Maps, Google Earth or another Google product, please?

Answer (score 1):

"`Failed: parse error`" message means that the KML document in the KMZ file is not a well-formed XML file.

A [KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) file is a ZIP file that includes a compressed KML file and optionally any referenced images or supporting KML files. One way to repair the KML file is to unzip the KML root document from the KMZ file (simply rename .kmz to .zip and treat as a zip file). Next view/edit KML file in a text editor (e.g. [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) that supports jumping to a particular line number in a large file.

After you uncompress the .kml file, you can check it by renaming it to have a .xml file extension and drag it onto your web browser. Modern web browsers perform basic XML checking and will complain when it sees an error.

Steps to locate and isolate errors in large KML files can be found here:
http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#KML_Validation_Tools

Sometimes the error is obvious such as missing a closing tag but more often it is not. The method to fix such problems is to comment out large parts of KML file until it validates as a well-formed XML file then work backwards and uncomment portions back until you've isolated the error. Once it is well-formed then you can use a [KML validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) to fully validate it if there are still problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error like this but the reason wasn't the bad kml's formatting. It was the bad data exported to Kml file.

Yeah, I my case, the Google Earth message was about "parsing".

What happened?

I had imported points data into ArcGIS but with mistaken the labels East by North and North by East. After, I exported points data to kml using ArcGIS. When I tried to open the file on Google Earth, it shown a Parsing error.

The solution was, of course change the label of the data.

My suggest:

**Check the data into Kmz.**

Perhaps this might help you.

Comment: This is something really simple, but this was choking me up as I had an "Advanced" label expression.  Simplified the label expression and it worked great, thanks!